# Django ORM: Filter results by values from list, limit answers per value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, greatest-n-per-group, django-orm

I'm using Django 2.0 and have a Content model with a ForeignKey(User, ...). I also have a list of user IDs for which I'd like to fetch that Content, ordered by "newest first", but only up to 25 elements per user. I know I can do this:

```
Content.objects.filter(user_id__in=[1, 2, 3, ...]).order_by('-id')
```

...to fetch all the Content objects created by each of these users, plus I'll get it all sorted with newest elements first. But I'd like to fetch up to 25 elements for each of these users (some users might create hundreds of these objects, some might create zero). There's of course the dumb way:

```
for user in [1, 2, 3, ...]:
    Content.objects.filter(user_id=user).order_by('-id')[:25]
```

This however hits the database as many times as there's objects in the user ID list, and that goes quite high (around 100 or so per page view). Is there any way to optimize this case? (I've tried looking around `select_related`, but that seems to fetch as many related models as possible.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to form a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query, but in this case you could form a union of top-n queries of all users:

```
contents = Content.objects.\
    none().\
    union(*[Content.objects.
            filter(user_id=uid).
            order_by('-id')[:25] for uid in user_ids],
          all=True)
```

Using [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) you could then produce a queryset that fetches the users and injects an attribute of latest content:

```
users = User.objects.\
    filter(id__in=user_ids).\
    prefetch_related(models.Prefetch(
        'content_set',
        queryset=contents,
        to_attr='latest_content'))
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work quite well. I'll try to grab some data over the next few days and come back with some data on how this performs.

Comment: You'll benefit of a `(user_id, id)` index, if you don't have one already. The individual queries of the union can use the `user_id` as access predicate and then range scan over `id`, so it avoids sorting. In Postgresql and at least in MySQL 8 you could define the index as `(user_id, id DESC)`, so it can be forward scanned directly.

Comment: On MySQL the explicit `id` in the index [might be redundant](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/17/can-mysql-use-primary-key-values-from-a-secondary-index/) for ORDER BY, given how InnoDB etc. work, but you'd have to check using EXPLAIN.

Comment: Also, I think Django indexes foreign key columns by default, so you might be covered already.

Comment: I'm actually running on PostgreSQL, and it does create this index by default.

Comment: On Postgresql you do need the 2 column index, if you want to avoid the sort. Of course if it's already performant enough without, you might not need to bother.

Answer (score 0):

Does it actually hit the database that many times? I have not looked at the raw SQL but according to the documentation it is equivalent to the `LIMIT` clause and it also states "Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

I would be curious to see the raw SQL if you are looking at it and it does NOT do this as I use this paradigm.

Comment: If I were just to fetch that QuerySet and not do anything with it, sure. But I actually need the QuerySet results and do iterate over those, thus evaluating the query.